# Comparing List and get indices in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, anaconda

I have a dataframe `A['name', 'frequency']` and a list B of 'name' Both are quite long. B is smaller one which I get on daily basis. I have to check whether element of B which is 'name' is there in DataFrame. `A['name']` if it is there i have to update the frequency of that 'name' in the dataframe every time it appears in B and if B has some new element I have to add that as a new row in DataFrame A with frequency 1. I have to do it in python 2.7. Thank you
A is my mac_list like this

```
mac_list.iloc[0:6]
Out[59]: 
mac_address  frequency
0  20c9d0892feb          2
1  28e34789c4c2          1
2  3480b3d51d5f          1
3  4480ebb4e28c          1
4  4c60de5dad72          1
5  4ca56dab4550          1
```

and B is my new_mac_list like this

```
['20c9d0892feb' '3480b3d51d5f' '20c9d0892feb' '249cji39fj4g']
```

I want a output for mac_list like

```
mac_address  frequency
0  20c9d0892feb          4
1  28e34789c4c2          1
2  3480b3d51d5f          2
3  4480ebb4e28c          1
4  4c60de5dad72          1
5  4ca56dab4550          1
6  249cji39fj4g          1
```

I have tried this

```
b = mac_list['mac_address'].isin(new_mac_list)
b=list(b)
for i in range(len(b)):
    if b[i]==True:
        mac_list['frequency'].iloc[i]+=1
```

to update the frequency but problem is frequency is increasing by one even if it appears more than 1 in new_mac_list

And I have used this to insert new element

```
c = new_mac_list.isin(mac_list['mac_address'])
c=list(c)
    for i in range(len(c)):
        if c[i]==False:
            mac_list.append(new_mac_list[i],1)
```

But it is very inefficient way I guess it can be done by comparing once only.

Comment: I have tried this


b = mac_list['mac_address'].isin(new_mac_list)
b=list(b)
for i in range(len(b)):
    if b[i]==True:
        mac_list['frequency'].iloc[i]+=1




to update the frequency but problem is frequency is increasing by one even if it appears more than 1 in new_mac_list





And I have used this to insert new element
c = new_mac_list.isin(mac_list['mac_address'])
c=list(c)
for i in range(len(c)):
    if c[i]==False:
        mac_list.append(new_mac_list[i],1)


But it is very inefficient way I guess it can be done by comparing once only

Comment: Please put it to your question and please refactor it. As for now it is unreadable.

Comment: Done. Please see it once and guide accordingly.

Comment: hey @pacholik  any help ??

Comment: hey@SimonGibbons ??

Comment: @DanishHussain please provide an example A, an example B, and the desired output.

Comment: done @IanS please help.

Comment: Have you tried using the `Counter` collection object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the initial dataframe:

```
mac_list

    mac_address  frequency
0  20c9d0892feb          2
1  28e34789c4c2          1
2  3480b3d51d5f          1
3  4480ebb4e28c          1
4  4c60de5dad72          1
5  4ca56dab4550          1
```

And the new list:

```
new_mac_list = ['20c9d0892feb', '3480b3d51d5f', '20c9d0892feb', '249cji39fj4g']
```

I'd first set the index of mac_list as mac_address:

```
mac_list = mac_list.set_index("mac_address")
```

And then calculate the frequencies in the new list:

```
new_freq = pd.Series(new_mac_list).value_counts()
```

You can then use the `add` method on the series:

```
res = mac_list["frequency"].add(new_freq, fill_value=0)

20c9d0892feb    4.0
249cji39fj4g    1.0
28e34789c4c2    1.0
3480b3d51d5f    2.0
4480ebb4e28c    1.0
4c60de5dad72    1.0
4ca56dab4550    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Back to the original format:

```
mac_list = pd.DataFrame(res, columns = ["frequency"])
print(mac_list)

              frequency
20c9d0892feb        4.0
249cji39fj4g        1.0
28e34789c4c2        1.0
3480b3d51d5f        2.0
4480ebb4e28c        1.0
4c60de5dad72        1.0
4ca56dab4550        1.0
```

Comment: hey @ayhan how can I convert this into previous format with indices as I have to do it on daily basis.I will get a new list daily.

Comment: What do you mean by "with indices"?

Comment: sorry typo mistake getting index as no, and column of mac_address back

Comment: In the end you have the mac_address as the index. You can try `mac_list.reset_index()` but I'd suggest leaving it as the index because I don't think setting and resetting index everyday would be very efficient.

Comment: Hey @ayhan one more question I have a huge list of mac_ids with some other variables in columns what I have to do i is to get the list of unique mac_ids with its frequency I have done it using lopp but that isnt efficient any help on that?

Comment: Convert the list to a pandas series and call value_counts() like I did in the answer (`pd.Series(new_mac_list).value_counts()`)

Comment: one last question i have created a series of mac_list applied valu_counts(). How to get a data frame with columns as unique mac_address and frequency of those mac_address
And can you suggest some source to read to get handy with this stuffs.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand your question. What you describe seems like the same thing as I did in the answer, in the last step.

Comment: the Data frames which are being created are of taking the values like integer or something I want to change that as string

Comment: just curious to know what does value = 0  does ??

Comment: `.add` is adding two dataframes by matching their indices. If an index exists in a dataframe but not in another, it can either display `NaN`, or take the `fill_value`. So it means take it as 0 when it does not exist in both.

Answer (score 0):

## Create index

If you talk efficiency, the index is the first thing that should come to mind.
I assume mac addresses are unique.

```
A = A.set_index("mac_address")
```

and access the items

```
A.loc[i]
```

the iteration over B is of minor relevance